# Progress of copy editor badge is shown incorrectly

Tags: bug, badge-progress

While reviweing one suggested edit, I found out this:

[image]

The popup says that I've edited 492 edits and still needs 8 edits to get copy editor badge. This information is not correct since I already have earned this badge. Is this a known issue?

Comment: It looks like your 158 votes above the Electorate badge. Where do you see you need 2 votes?

Comment: @FDinoff where do you read 2?

Comment: @Cole the post was edited to fix that.

Comment: cosmic rays again.